# why is there a need to sanitize data on output to the browser

Tags: php, sql

I've noticed on a few SQL injection protection tutorials, that the tutor will say something like "**you must sanitize all user data when it is output to the page**" - or something along the lines of that..

However, I am confused as to why this is necessary to do so.

One of the reasons for that would be; don't you normally escape and sanitize data on input into the database, thus removing the need to then re-sanitize it on output once again..

Just seems a bit pointless to me, and I've been searching around looking for an answer as to why this is needed, but I can't seem to find any pages which explain how it will protect against any attacks.

If someone could fill me in, that would be greatly appreciated,

thanks.

Comment: You don't escape input anymore when you use Prepared Statements. You only escaped because of SQL Injections. You sanitize the output because of XSS. You convert html special characters into their representative html code, so that the browser doesn't parse it as HTML.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois please see edit. I seem to have mixed up sanitize & escape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases are not webpages.

What makes data safe to be placed in a string of SQL is not the same as what makes data safe to be placed in an HTML document.

Even if it was, the act of reading the data from the database would give you the unescaped data. To take a trivial example: Given `INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES ('John', 'O\'Brian'):`, the `\` is not inserted into the database. It just stops the `'` from ending the string in the SQL.

---

When you insert data into a database, you need to escape it (or use prepared statements) to defend against SQL Injection attacks.

When you insert data into a webpage, you need to escape it (or use a DOM based whitelist filter) to defend against XSS attacks.

Now you *could* try to defend against XSS when you insert the data into the database instead of when you insert it into the page, but that is premature and can cause bigger issues down the line. It means you'll be storing HTML in the database instead of text, which is less useful if you decide you want to use the text for some other purpose (like inserting into an email or just being searched).

Comment: I know that `\\`` is used to escape data. But what about the `htmlspecialchars` (for example) function? Why use that twice for no reason (on input and output). Seems a bit skewif to me. Sorry for the kind of strange question, just very curious

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic — You don't. You use it when you insert the data into HTML. You don't use it when you insert the data into SQL.

Comment: ohh. Strange, most of the tutorials I've seen have looked at it differently and either just sanitize data on input **OR** sanitize data on input & ouput.

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic — For the reasons I outlined in the answer, escaping on input is a bad idea. It traps you with escaped data when you might not want it.

Comment: oh okay :) I've gotcha now, thanks for the answer! gave me a better insight

Answer (score -1):

First, tutorials including that you should escape the data before inserting it into the database are most often bad or outdated. Always use prepared statements with parameters instead of manually escaping the data.

Escaping of output data is to prevent cross site scripting (XSS) attacks against your users.